# bindings.node' was compiled against a different Node.js version usingNODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires NODE_MODULE_VERSION 89

Tags: javascript, node.js, binding, electron, electron-builder

I am trying to make an electron app run on my pc. On ubuntu it works, i am having issues with windows. When i try to run my application i get this error

The module '\?\C:\Users\david\Desktop\Serial_Communication\node_modules@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 89. 
Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1846)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:18)
at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1846)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:935:32)
at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:14)
at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12913)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at bindings (C:\Users\david\Desktop\Serial_Communication\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:112:48)
at Object. (C:\Users\david\Desktop\Serial_Communication\node_modules@serialport\bindings\lib\win32.js:1:36)

I have already tried npm install, npm rebuild, electron-rebuild, and it does not work. It seems also strange to me that it suggests me to use an older version of Node, any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. I used this link https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/releases/tag/%40serialport%2Fbindings%409.2.0 and downloaded the version v89 of the binding module. Then i manually imported that version into the @serialport/bindings folder.

Comment: Did you just copy and paste the folder into the @serialport/bindings folder replacing the other one?